# How to translate MySQL regexp to Postgres?

Tags: mysql, regex, postgresql, pdo

1. I have such MySQL query:

> ```
> '... WHERE    
>     LOWER(users.name) REGEXP LOWER(" '.$q.'") OR
>     LOWER(users.name) REGEXP LOWER("^'.$q.'") OR
>     LOWER(users.login) REGEXP LOWER("'.$q.'") OR 
>     links.lv REGEXP LOWER("'.$q.'+")'
> ```

and I need to prepare this same condition in PostgreSQL and PDO. I was trying with regexp_matches(), but it didn't work with PDO.

Comment: Have you looked at the [PostgreSQL pattern matching documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html)?

Comment: What were you trying with PDO and what error messages did you get? PS: standard SQL (include PostgreSQL) uses double quotes for identifiers (such as table and column names), single quotes are for string literals. And please don't use string wrangling to build SQL, it is rarely needed.

Comment: Learn to use prepared statements, otherwise say welcome to sql injections

Comment: What's `$q`? Show us the PHP code that invokes this SQL and the **exact text of any error message**.

Comment: In future, please always give us the PostgreSQL version, exact error messages, and explain what you've tried, with code.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on fixing your regexp, the error message would be needed, but I'm guessing Postgres is spitting out a column not found error or something to that order if your original query is anything to go by. The reason is that you're using double quotes; these are used to quote identifiers in Postgres, in much the same way as backticks are in MySQL.

Also note that Postgres offers something better than what you're trying to achieve with the query you posted, in the form of full text search. To illustrate, you could use something like:

```
...
where (setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(users.name,  '')), 'A') ||
       setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(users.login, '')), 'B') ||
       setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(users.bio,   '')), 'D') ||
       setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(links.lv,    '')), 'B')
      ) @@ plainto_tsquery(:query)
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown us what `$q` is, so it's rather hard to guess what you're trying to do. If it's a regular expression you'd do something like:

```
WHERE    
    LOWER(users.name) ~ :q OR
    LOWER(users.name) ~ :q OR
    LOWER(users.login) ~ :q OR 
    links.lv ~ :q
```

where `:q` is a *placeholder variable* that you pass as a *named query parameter*. See [PDO::Prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

I strongly suspect that your `$q` is actually just something like `.*somestring.*`, i.e. you're just doing an infix pattern search. If that's the case you'd really be better off using `LIKE` instead of MySQL `REGEXP` or PostgreSQL `~` and using the pattern `%somestring%`.

**Do not interpolate text straight into your SQL like you do above**.

[image: Bobby Tables]

What happens if `$q` is `"); DROP TABLE users; --` ? Oops! Please read:

- [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)
- [PHP manual on SQL injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)
- [Wikipedia on SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)